# jquery cannot get value updated dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I updated the value of input on an event and called a function to calculate it. but the function cannot read the inputs value. In the below example i have to caluclate the total when i press the price button. 
    http://jsfiddle.net/LkaA7/4/

```
// on change of quantity - works
$('.qty').on('change', function(){
    calculate();
});

// on change of price - works
$('.price').on('change', function(){
calculate();
});

// on clicking button - not working
$('p.button').on('click', function(){
    var price = $(this).data('price');
    /*** in my project this val is generated by ajax call  ***/
    $('.price').val(price);
    /***** ******/

    calulate();    
});   

function calculate(){
    var qty = $('.qty'),
        pr = $('.price'),
        tot = $('.total'),
        cal = 0;
    cal = qty.val()*pr.val();
    tot.val(cal);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Maybe it would help if you spelled `calculate` right … and not `calulate`. -1, because your browser’s error console would have told you that already without asking here.

Comment: Yes it works, but its not working in my project with ajax call. i will look where the prop lies

Comment: show us all your code with ajax call so we can see where it goes wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for fun, I took a slightly different approach. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/LkaA7/8/)

The price change was switched to .blur.
Error checking for numeric input in price was added.

JS

```
$('.qty').on('change', function(){
    calculate();
});

$('.price').blur(function(){
    calculate();
});

$('.button').on('click', function(){
    calculate();
});

function calculate(){
    var pr = $('.price').val();
    if( isNaN(+pr) )
      { 
        pr = 0;
       }
  var qty = $('.qty').val();
  tot = qty * pr;
  $('.total').val(tot);
}
```